# how to secure username password when calling remote restful api in web/mobile?

Tags: rest, restkit

here is my script of php to call remote restful api, the username password are hard coded in source code,

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/m1/m1apiserver/public/api/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "email=elson%40bla.com&password=bla");

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$json = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

$j = json_decode($json);
// further processing ....
if ($j->token) {
    //echo $j->token;
    $output = file_get_contents("http://localhost/m1/m1apiserver/public/api/product?token=".$j->token);
    echo $output;
}
```

but are there any techniques to secure the username password?

Comment: please define "secure". Is it a communication issue? Is it a storage issue?